# Action of $SO_n$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ induces fibre bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions, fiber-bundles, fibration

Real compact Lie group $SO_n$ acts smoothly and transitively on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with obvious action. Isotropy subgroup of each point in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is isomoprhic to $SO_{n-1}$. Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be standard orthonormal base for $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to see that map
$$p \colon SO_n \to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$$
$$A \mapsto A e_n$$
is fibre bundle.

Map $p$ is obviously continuous surjection. I suppose one could take open cover $\{U^+,U^-\}$ of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, where $U^\pm := \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \setminus \{\pm e_n\}$. Now, I should construct two homeomorphisms $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, such that the following diagrams commute:

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d3q3c51571a2oj2s6x67154w1s5p653g.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d2t125i2a6r5ls674c44f4v5i5x3m26.png))</sub>

I cannot make this happen. How to define $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$? Or should I use some other cover? Any help would be appreciated.

The reason I want this is that I would like to use homotopy lifting property (or exact sequence of homotopy groups) to calculate fundamental groups of $SO_n$ by induction.

Comment: A very general theorem that tells you this is a locally trivial fibration is Ehresmann's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann's_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a compact Lie group and $H$ is a closed subgroup, then $G\rightarrow G/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle. In particular, it is a fibre bundle with fibre $H$.

So, $SO(n)\rightarrow SO(n)/SO(n-1)$ is a fibre bundle with fibre $SO(n-1)$. We then compose this quotient map with the diffeomorphism $SO(n)/SO(n-1)\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ to get a fibre bundle $SO(n)\rightarrow S^{n-1}$. It then just remains to compute this map. It is precisely $A\mapsto[A]\mapsto Ae_n$, as desired.

Comment: Could you please provide reference for the fact that compact Lie group and closed subgroup induce principal bundle?

Comment: The general result is that if a compact Lie group $K$ acts freely on a manifold $X$, then there is a unique manifold structure on the quotient space $X/K$ for which $X\rightarrow X/K$ is a principal $K$-bundle. In our case, $H$ is compact since it is closed inside something compact. Also, it acts freely on $G$ via $h:g\mapsto gh^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}$Your cover of $S^{n-1}$ is suitable.

Let $x = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n-1})$ denote an element of $\R^{n-1}$, let $\Pi:U^{+} \to \R^{n-1}$ be stereographic projection from $e_{n}$, i.e.,
$$
\Pi(x, x_{n}) = \frac{x}{1 - x_{n}},\quad
\|x\|^{2} + x_{n}^{2} = 1,\ x_{n} \neq 1,
$$
and let $\Sigma:\R^{n-1} \to U^{+}$ be the inverse map
$$
\Sigma(x) = \left(\frac{2x}{\|x\|^{2} + 1}, \frac{\|x\|^{2} - 1}{\|x\|^{2} + 1}\right).
$$
Since $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ are diffeomorphisms, they define a trivialization $\alpha: p^{-1}(U^{+}) \to U^{+} \times SO(n-1)$.

More explicitly, the columns $v_{1}, \dots, v_{n-1}$ of the Jacobian $D\Sigma(x)$ are a basis for $T_{\Sigma(x)} U^{+}$. Conveniently, they're also mutually orthogonal and of equal length since stereographic projection is conformal. Consequently, if $A \in SO(n - 1)$, and if $e = \{e_{1}, \dots, e_{n-1}\}$ denotes the Cartesian frame on $\R^{n-1}$, then
$$
\Sigma_{*}(x, Ae)
  = \bigl(\Sigma(x), D\Sigma(x)(Ae)\bigr)
  = \bigl(\Sigma(x), A\, D\Sigma(x)(e)\bigr)
  = \bigl(\Sigma(x), Av)\bigr).
$$
In words, under the diffeomorphism $\Sigma$, the standard left action of $SO(n-1)$ on the frame bundle of $\R^{n-1}$ induces the left action of $SO(n-1)$ on the frame bundle of $U^{+}$.

If $\tilde{A}$ is an element of $SO(n)$ whose last column is not $e_{n}$, and if the columns of $\tilde{A}$ are denoted $f_{1}, \dots, f_{n-1}, f_{n}$, there exists a unique $x$ in $\R^{n-1}$ such that $\Sigma(x) = f_{n}$, and there exists a unique $A$ in $SO(n-1)$ such that the orthogonal frames $f = (f_{1}, \dots, f_{n-1})$ and $Av = (Av_{1}, \dots, Av_{n-1})$ in $T_{f_{n}}(U^{+})$ are proportional. This correspondance defines the trivialization $\alpha_{1}$.

To trivialize this bundle over $U^{-}$, proceed similarly, but instead of stereographic projection $\Pi^{-}$ from the south pole (which reverses orientation), use $\Pi^{-}$ followed by the map $x_{1} \mapsto -x_{1}$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the last part, which starts with "More explicitly" :).  I see that conformality of stereographich projection implies that Jacobian $D\Sigma^\pm$ is orthogonal operator, but why does it have positive determinant?

Comment: Moreover, I don't see how is $p^{-1}(U^\pm)$ identified via $\Pi^\pm$, and how is $(\Sigma^\pm(x),e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ its orthonormal frame. How to think about $p^{-1}(U^+)$, besides matrices which don't have $e_n$ as fixed point?

Comment: And I couldn't figure out how to connect story from last paragraph with my desired trivializations. How can I write $\alpha^+(A) = (A e_n,$ some $SO_{n-1}$ matrix$)$?

Comment: You're right about orientation for the "southern" projection, and it may be a day or few before I have time to address your other comments. If I can't fix things in a timely manner I'll delete this answer, since Peter Crooks' approach appears to suit your needs.

Comment: Please don't delete your answer, because someday I might be able to fill all the details myself.