# Understanding $\pi_3O(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm reading Hatcher and trying to understand his statement about the Bott periodicity for the orthogonal group $O(n)$.  Using the fiber bundle structure $O(n-1)\hookrightarrow O(n) \to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, and assuming a large enough $n$, we know that $\pi_k\left (\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\right ) = 0$ for $k<n-1$, hence in lower dimensions this sets up isomorphisms $\pi_kO(n-1) \cong \pi_kO(n)$ for $k<n-2$ via the long exact sequence

$$
\ldots \to \;\; \pi_kO(n-1) \;\; \to \;\; \pi_kO(n)\;\; \to \;\; \pi_k\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to \pi_{k-1}O(n-1) \;\; \to \ldots
$$

The thing I don't understand is his computation of $\pi_3O(n) = \mathbb{Z}$.  The way I originally argued this to myself is that there is essentially a chain of isomorphisms $\pi_kO(p) \cong \pi_kO(q)$ for $p \leq q$, hence we could reduce this to
$$
\pi_3O(n) \;\; \cong \;\; \pi_3O(3) \;\; \cong \;\; \pi_3 \left (\mathbb{RP}^3\right ) \;\; \cong \;\; \pi_3\left (\mathbb{S}^3\right ) \;\; =\;\; \mathbb{Z}
$$

where the congruence $\pi_3 \left (\mathbb{RP}^3\right ) \cong \pi_3\left (\mathbb{S}^3\right )$ comes from the covering space isomorphism.  However, if I'm understanding the chain of isomorphisms correctly (which I'm probably not), then couldn't we argue that

$$
\pi_3O(n) \;\; \cong \;\; \pi_3O(2) \;\; \cong \;\; \pi_3\left (\mathbb{S}^1\right ) \;\; = \;\; 0?
$$

I'm self-studying topology and don't have too many people to discuss this with.  I'd like to understand the root of my misunderstanding.  For reference, the statement as claimed in Hatcher is the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{ l | cccccccc}
i \; \text{mod} \; 8 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ \hline
\pi_iO(n) & \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mathbb{Z}_2 & 0 & \mathbb{Z} & 0 & 0& 0 & \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I haven't looked at it thoroughly but one thing that you have to be careful about is that the isomorphism holds when $k<n-1.$ Fixing a $k$ it is not true that $\pi_k(O(n))\cong \pi_k(O(m))$ for all $m<n$ but only in the range $n-1>m>k$

Comment: @ShubhankarSahai That's helpful to understand, but that wasn't clearly explained in Hatcher for some reason.  In computing $\pi_3O(n)$, could we then argue that $\pi_3O(n) \cong \pi_3O(4)$?

Comment: The chain comes from the fibre sequences $O_{n-1}\rightarrow O_n\rightarrow S^{n-1}$. Hence there is an exact sequence $\pi_3O_2\rightarrow \pi_3O_3\rightarrow \pi_3S^2\rightarrow \pi_2O_2$. Since $\pi_3O_2=0$ and $\pi_2O_2=0$ you have $\pi_3O_3\cong\pi_3S^2\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Mnifldz I realised that there is typo in the range, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue lies with you assumption that 
$$\pi_k(O(n))=\pi_k(O(m))$$ for all $m\leq n.$
This is not true.

In general you have a fibration $O(n-1)\to O(n)\to S^{n-1}.$ Now $S^{n-1}$ has no homotopy in degrees less than $n-1$ and $\pi_{n-1}S^{n-1}=\mathbf{Z}.$

So in the long exact sequence you get

$$\ldots\to\pi_{n}S^{n-1}\to \pi_{n-1}O(n-1)\to \pi_{n-1}O(n)\to \pi_{n-1}S^{n-1}\to \pi_{n-2}O(n)\to \pi_{n-2}O(n-1)\to 0 $$
so in particular $$\pi_{n-1}O(n)\neq \pi_{n-1}O(n-1),$$ and also $$\pi_{n-2}O(n)\neq \pi_{n-2}O(n-1).$$

However from the same construction you can note that

$$\pi_{n-i}O(n-1)\cong \pi_{n-i}O(n)$$ for all $i>2.$

In general you can conclude from the same arguments that
$$\pi_k(O(n))\cong \pi_{k}(O(n-1))$$ whenever $n>k+2$

Note that the computation in Hatcher is for the stable range i.e. large enough $n$ so that the homotopy groups start stabilising. It is not for all $n$, specifially lower dimension $n$.

In particular, the full periodicity shows up for the group
$$O=\varinjlim O(n)$$

Comment: I'm still not fully satisfied because I don't see the argument for why $\pi_3O(n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Looking at Tyrone's comment above, I understand why $\pi_3O(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, but why is it true for higher $n$?  It may be best if I include the table that Hatcher has in his book...

Comment: @Mnifldz Oh I see, your issue. Note that the table in Hatcher is for large n.
In particular note that there is a fibration 
$O(3)\to O(4)\to  S^3.$ This gives on the homotopy groups  $\ldots \pi_{3}O(3)\to \pi_{3}(O(4))\to \pi_{3}S^3\to \ldots,$ but note that none of the groups on either side is $0$ so $\pi_3O(4)$ is not $\mathbf{Z}.$
The $\pi_3$ start stabilising for $O(n)$ with $n>5.$

Comment: The crux of the computation in Hatcher is that for large enough $n$ the homotopy groups of $O(n)$ are independent of $n$. Now the homotopy is $8$ periodic. So for large enough $n$ we only need to understand the homotopy upto $\pi_7$. In this case we need $n$ to be  larger than 8.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting the impression that Hatcher's treatment of this is not fully explicit/detailed.  He seems to like to give previews to more advanced topics without giving the full machinery for understanding them.

Comment: @Mnifldz yes I think this particular section in Hatcher is more for culture. A place to learn the proof of Bott Periodicity is Milnor's Classic book on Morse Theory. This is the most elementary proof I know of. There are other simpler proofs but they require too much machinery, such as Harris' proof using simplicial techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Left translation on the Lie group $O(n)$ induces homeomorphisms between path components, so there is a homeomorphism (diffeomorphism)
$$O_n\cong SO_n\times\mathbb{Z}_2,\qquad \forall n.$$
In particular 
$$\pi_kSO_n\cong\pi_kO_n,\qquad \forall k\geq1.$$
Using the fibration sequences
$$SO_{n-1}\rightarrow SO_n\rightarrow S^{n-1}$$
we see that what we really need to compute is $\pi_3SO_5$. That is, 
$$\pi_3O_n\cong\pi_3SO_5,\qquad\forall n\geq5.$$
Here we have used nothing more than $\pi_kS^n=0$ for $k<n$, $\pi_nS^n\cong\mathbb{Z}$, and exactness of the homotopy sequence of a fibration. In particular we have not calculated any of the homomorphisms in any sequence, save for when they are isomorphisms or trivial.

The easiest way to compute $\pi_3SO_5$ is to know something about its universal cover. By definition, the universal cover of $SO_n$ is the spinor group $Spin_n$. Since $\pi_1SO_n\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n\geq 3$ ($\pi_1SO_1=0$ and $\pi_1SO_2\cong\mathbb{Z}$), we have a 2-sheeted universal cover and a fibration
$$\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow Spin_n\rightarrow SO_n.$$

In the special case $n=5$, as it happens, there is an exceptional isomorphism
$$Spin_5\cong Sp_2$$
(i.e. a smooth group isomorphism). Now $Sp_n$ is the group of orthogonal transformations of the quaternionic space $\mathbb{H}^n$. This is defined in exactly the same way as the $SO_n$, with $\mathbb{R}^n$ replaced by $\mathbb{H}^n$, and the Euclidean inner product with the quaternionic form $(q_1,q_2)\mapsto q_1\overline q_2$. For the same reaons we have the fibration sequences for the $SO_n$, we have fibration sequences
$$Sp_{n-1}\rightarrow Sp_n\rightarrow S^{4n-1}.$$
The factor of $4$ which appears can be traced to the fact that $\mathbb{H}$ is 4-dimensional over the reals, so the unit sphere in $\mathbb{H}^n$ is $S^{4n-1}$.

Now $Sp_1\cong SU_2\cong Spin_3\cong S^3$, so for $n=2$ the fibration sequence above is
$$S^3\rightarrow Sp_2\rightarrow S^7.$$
In particular 
$$\pi_3Sp_2\cong \pi_3S^3\cong \mathbb{Z}$$
and hence
$$\pi_3SO_5\cong \pi_3Spin_5\cong\mathbb{Z}.$$

Some comments on $\pi_3SO_n$ for $n<5$. We have $\pi_3SO_1=0$, since $SO_1$ is trivial. We have $\pi_3SO_2=0$, since $SO_2\cong S^1$ as the unit circle in the complex plane. We have $\pi_3SO_3\cong \mathbb{Z}$ as pointed out in the comments. As a space $SO_3$ is homeomorphic (diffeomorphic) to $\mathbb{R}P^3$ and to the unit sphere bundle in the tangent bundle of $S^2$ (using $SO_2\cong S^1$, the fibration sequence introduced above actually is the fibring of the unit tangent bundle over $S^2$).

The group $SO_n$ is simple for $n\neq 4$, and the final special case is that $SO_4$ is not simple. The fibration sequence $SO_3\rightarrow SO_4\rightarrow S^3$ splits (i.e. has a section).  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629328/how-can-so4-cong-so3-times-s3-if-the-fiber-bundle-so3-rightarrow-so) for a nice discussion. In any case this implies that there is a homeomorphism (diffeomorphism)
$$SO_4\cong SO_3\times S^3$$
and in particular
$$\pi_3SO_4\cong\pi_3SO_3\oplus\pi_3S^3$$
(this group is $\mathbb{Z}^2$).